# Node.js, Express, jQuery.param() - Remove quotes from JSON

Tags: jquery, node.js, serialization, express, quotes

I am serializing a JSON object on the client using jQuery.param():

```
var test = {"coordinates":[[-122.610168,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.598167]]};

console.log($.param( test ));
```

After making a GET request, on the server side within an Express route, I access the object with:

```
console.log('Server received: ' + JSON.stringify(req.query.coordinates));
```

This outputs the below - note the quotes around each coordinate:

```
Server received: [["-122.610168","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.598167"]]
```

How can I remove the quotes? I can parse to a string and use a regex then parse back to JSON, but that seems inefficient. Can anyone advise what part of the process is adding them and how they can be removed?

Comment: You can behave with `req.query.coordinates` like a normal array, run for on it and run `parseFloat` on each member of it. If you don't understand I can post sample code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something tells me there's a way to do this in a single, chained function call by using `bind`, but the best I could come up with was:

```
var coords = data.map(function(arr){return arr.map(parseFloat);})
```

This has the benefit of being non-destructive (the original `data` variable remains intact).

Answer (score 1):

Just try like bellow

```
var data = [["-122.610168","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.598167"],["-122.288818","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.845833"],["-122.610168","37.598167"]]

data.forEach(function(arr){
   arr[0] = +arr[0];
   arr[1] = +arr[1];
})

console.log(data)// prints[[-122.610168,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.598167],[-122.288818,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.845833],[-122.610168,37.598167]]
```